# Javascript undefined issue

Tags: javascript, undefined

```
            if(typeof(GUEST_IDS) != undefined){
          GUEST_IDS = GUEST_IDS.substr(1);
          GUEST_IDS = GUEST_IDS.split(",");
          for(GP in GUEST_POINTS){
            GUEST_ON = 0;
            for(GID in GUEST_IDS){
              if(GUEST_IDS[GID] == GP){
                GUEST_ON = 1;
              }
            }
            if(GUEST_ON == 0){
              GUEST_POINTS[GP].setVisible(false);
            }
          }
        }else{
          for(GP in GUEST_POINTS){
            GUEST_POINTS[GP].setVisible(false);
          }
        }
```

when I alert GUEST_IDS it says undefined, so if GUEST_IDS = undefined why is the code running as if if(typeof(GUEST_IDS) != undefined){ is true?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`typeof` returns a string specifying the type. Also, `typeof` does not require parens, and it's good practice to use `!==` over `!=`:

```
if(typeof GUEST_IDS !== "undefined") {
```

Other points:

- Don't capitalize everything
- Use `var`
- Use a normal `for` loop to iterate over an array; not a `for in` loop
- Don't overwrite existing variables; `GUEST_IDS` is changing from a string to an array
- Use `===` rather than `==`
- You can use chaining like `var ids = GUEST_IDS.substr(1).split(",");`

Comment: Thanks pimvdb! I cannot believe I forgot it returns a string, space. lol

Comment: Wait, the upper part of the code has GUEST_IDS = null; So why when I do typeof GUEST_IDS, it says Object when alerted?

Comment: @Shane Larson: Yes, `typeof null === "object"`. It is indeed not undefined. You might want just `if(GUEST_IDS) {` instead. This condition will allow anything except `undefined`, `null`, and some other "falsy" values.

Comment: Why does null = Object, when its null not an Object?

Comment: @Shane Larson: I don't know who invented that, but it's literally in the specification: http://es5.github.com/x11.html#x11.4.3.

Comment: That is dumb... Makes no sense.

Comment: @Shane Larson: It has been corrected in the upcoming version, though: http://wiki.ecmascript.org/doku.php?id=harmony:typeof_null.